# Reversing a Linked List Through a Double Pointer

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am attempting to reverse a linked through a double pointer and gcc keeps giving me exit status -1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
  struct Node * link;
} Node;

Node ** reverse(Node ** rootp)
{
  if ( ( rootp == NULL )|| ( (*rootp) == NULL) || (((*rootp)->link) == NULL) )
  {
    return rootp;
  }

  Node ** old_previous = (Node **)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  Node ** previous = (Node **)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  previous = rootp;

  Node ** current = (Node **)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  current = &((*rootp)->link);

  ((*previous)->link) = NULL;


  while ( ((*current)->link) != NULL )
  {
    old_previous = previous;

    previous = current;

    current = &((*current)->link);

    ((*previous)->link) = (*old_previous);

  }

  ((*current)->link) = (*previous);

  free(old_previous);

  free(previous);

  free(current);

  return current;
}

void print_list(Node * root)
{
  if ( root == NULL )
  { return; }

  if (root->link == NULL)
  { printf("%p\n\n",root); return; }

  printf("%p ",root);

  print_list(root->link);
}

int main(void) 
{
  Node * first = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  Node * second = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  Node * third = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));

  first->link = second;

  second->link = NULL;

  third->link = NULL;

  print_list(first);

  Node ** rev = reverse(&first);

  print_list(*rev);

  free(first);

  free(second);

  free(third);

  return 0;
}
```

Since gcc simply reports exit status -1, I guess I must be dereferencing a NULL node somewhere in the reverse function. When a friend of mine translated the idea of the reverse function into a python program, it worked just fine. There must be a pointer problem somewhere in the reverse function. Do any of you have any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you all for considering.

Comment: First thing that I see: you can't `free(current)` and then `return current`

Comment: why are you using a `double pointer` to traverse the list?

Comment: I am not trying to copy and reverse at the same time. As I traverse through a linked list, the previous node will be linked to the previous previous node.

Comment: I am using a double pointer since a later function must accept the memory address of the pointer of the tail node as input

Comment: Oh, and thanks for reminding me that you cannot free(current) and return current user3386109.

Comment: Why are you casting the result of `malloc()`. Are you using a C++-compiler to compile C Code? Don't

Comment: No, Swordfish, I am not using a C++ compiler, I am using the gcc compiler on C Online REPL.

Comment: But, since you're returning the new head, you can just use a `single` pointer, and you can pass the address of head to that later function.  I think you're making things way more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: I guess you are right bruceg. Still, I don't see what is wrong with my double pointer reverse function.

Comment: @TanveerSalim then don't cast the result of `malloc()`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any malloc's inside a reverse function.  You just need to switch the `link` field around as you traverse the list.

Comment: @TanveerSalim Also you `free()` your originally allocated memory at the end of `main()` that is already `free()`d in your `reverse()`-function. that won't work.

Comment: You are right bruceg, I removed the malloc's and just assigned the memory addresses of the pointers to the nodes directly to the double pointers in reverse function.

Comment: Then I will delete the frees in the reverse function--Swordfish.

Comment: There are numerous questions on SO about how to reverse a list, and at least some of them use a pointer to pointer (colloquially, a 'double pointer', but that's ambiguous with `double *` which is also a double pointer).  How many did you find?  Are you positive that none of them are any help?

Comment: Is it gcc giving you an exit -1 or is the result of gcc, you executable, which when executed returns -1?

Comment: Hi everyone, I realized the problem using a debugger. Due to (*previous)->link = NULL;, the memory address referred to by *current becomes NULL itself, generating the exit status -1 problem. This proves it is a bad idea to use a double pointer to reverse a linked list and I have already found another solution to the problem. Thank you to all for your time.